# Test suites for java - what is it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing

I have to submit my project along with test suits. I would appreciate someone explaining best with example what is it, is there some other tools that build the test or is it a scenario written by myself? I have never written it before so please any info will be of a great help.

Comment: If you had to write your code following `tdd` - you've already failed the task. `tdd` means you write the tests first, and your code - after that. Anyway: google for `junit`

Comment: OK, in that case I should remove TDD from the tags. Thanks.

Comment: What is this project for? Where did the requirement for a test suite come from? Tests come in many forms. You should ask your "client" what they expect as far as testing goes.

Comment: I've heard that a test suit is just a fancy name for the overalls that they put on a crash test dummy.  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test suite is nothing else but group of UnitTest.

Suppose You have a couple of test: UserDAOTest, BooksDAOTest, BorrowsDAOTest, etc...

```
public class DAOSuite{
    Class[] testClasses = {
        UserDAOTest.class,
        BooksDAOTest.class,
        BorrowsDAOTest.class
    };
    TestSuite = new TestSuite(testClasses);
}
```

Alternatively You can do above with annotations style too. Then just run your test suite(s) same way you run jUnit tests.

Additional info [1]

[1] http://www.junit.org/apidocs/junit/framework/TestSuite.html

Comment: I would disagree with this answer cause it narrows down the idea of test suite pretty much. Stephen C provided better explanation.

Answer (score 2):

Lukasz Siwinski states:

> "Test suite is nothing else but group of UnitTest."

That is not entirely accurate.

A "test suite" CAN be just a group of unit tests.  But it can also include larger scale tests (system tests or integration tests) that are designed to test the larger scale behaviour of a system.

The Wikipedia page on [System Testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_testing) provides an overview of the *kinds* of things that may be tested at the system level.

---

In your case, unit tests may be sufficient to satisfy the project requirements.  But I'd advise you to clarify this with the project supervisors.